# How to use Applet getParamter in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, getparameter

I have a simple Java Applet (SE 7) with an HTML file containing Applet and Param elements.

GetParameter() works fine hitting the HTML page with a browser or using appletviewer, but when I run the app in Eclipse (Juno Build id: 20130225-0426) the debugger shows GetParamter() returns null for every call.

The class and html files are in the bin directory of the project.  Should this just work or is there some configuration I need to make when setting this up or launching in Eclipse.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found one approach that seems to work (from the Eclipse site).

Select the Applet -> run configurations -Parameters and manually enter the parameter names and values.

It works but this doesn't appear to exercise the getParameter() HTML interaction using Eclipse.  SO I'm back to appletviewer to ensure my HTML works properly with my Java class from what I can tell.